# Get a list of channels managed from an account using Youtube api?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to retrieve a list of channels managed from 1 account using Youtube api and oath2.0. I am creating a console application, to set up the oath2.0 I have created the application type as other in developers console. Now when I run the application for the first time its launching the browser and asking me to authenticate and select a channel as well. This is the code I am using for authentication:
'''

```
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
            CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;
            UserCredential credential;
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(

                new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = "XXXXXX",
                    ClientSecret = "XXXXX"
                },               
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl, YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubepartnerChannelAudit, YouTubeService.Scope.Youtubepartner },
                "<UserID>",
                ct,
                new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
            );

            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
            });
```

'''

As I am selecting only 1 channel, I am not able to get a list of all the channels managed in the account.
I am trying to access the channels using the following api:

'''

```
            var channelsinStream = youtubeService.Channels.List("snippet,contentDetails,statistics");

            channelsinStream.Mine = true;

            var channelresponse = await channelsinStream.ExecuteAsync();
```

'''

The main motto of this is to delete all the live videos in the channels once they are added. We have close to 100 channels so its difficult to go through each channel everytime to delete them.